# NameError: name 'Window' is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyautogui

Почему возникает эта ошибка? помогите,пожалуйста

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore,QtTest
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
import keyboard, pyautogui, os

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.set()

    def set(self):
        self.w_goldhunter = uic.loadUiType("goldhunter.ui")
        self.w_goldhunter.btn_more.clicked.connect(self.thread)


    def thread(self):
      while keyboard.is_pressed("Esc") == False:

       for f in files:

        picture = "syndyk/" + f

        button = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(picture, confidence = 0.95)

        if button:
            pyautogui.click(button)
            pyautogui.sleep(0.1)

app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
form = Form()
form.setupUi(window)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Назовите class Window Удалите  form = Form() form.setupUi(window) Запустите sys.exit(app.exec_()) У Вас сегодня домашнее задание по QT - куча однотипных вопросов :))))

Comment: спасибо, я просто пытаюсь с ним разобраться:D

Comment: MsDasha,  для начала, рекомендую вам разобраться с PEP 8 - руководство по написанию кода на Python https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html